# List of Object not loading properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am created List of object class and return from CreateListFromTable method. But always Virtual method is calling and throwing exception. Data is not loading into List.

What could be the problem?

```
 public static List<Customer> GetCustomer(string ID)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            DatabaseGateway da = new DatabaseGateway();
            dt = da.QueryForDataTable("proc_GetCustomer", ID);                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogMessage(ex.Message + ":  " + ex.StackTrace, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }

        return CreateListFromTable<Customer>(dt);          


    }

 protected static List<T> CreateListFromTable<T>(DataTable dt) where T : BusinessObject, new()
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        try
        {          
            if (dt != null)
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                T t = new T();
                t.Load(row);
                list.Add(t);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {


        }
        return list;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Virtual method which should be overriden by inherited types that support loading.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="row"></param>
    protected virtual void Load(DataRow row)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("The object of type '" + this.GetType().Name +
            "' does not support loading from DataRow.");
    }
```

Comment: {"The object of type 'Customer' does not support loading from DataRow."}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `Customer` inherit `BusinessObject`?

```
public class Customer : BusinessObject
```

And, do you override the method properly (assuming the code for the `Load` method from this class is is `BusinessObject`)?

```
protected override void Load(DataRow row)
```

Also, I noticed that the `Load` method is `protected` and it looks like you're calling a public `Load` method on `t`. This could cause some confusion as to what methods are actually being called since you can't override a protected method with a public one (Compiler error: `Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'BaseClass.ProtectedMethod' is less accessible than class 'DerivedClass.ProtectedMethod'`).

Answer (score 0):

You got to catch for each iteration, instead of wrapping the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method extensible `.ToList()` in LINQ to pass the datatable to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a method that looks like this in the Customer class?

```
protected override void Load(DataRow row)
{
    ...
}
```

Also, could you make the BusinessObject class abstract and make the Load method `abstract` instead of `virtual` to ensure that this does not happen?